# A real analysis question based on a given defination and then finding the condition on the function

Tags: real-analysis

This question was asked in a master exam for which I am preparing.

> Let $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a function for which there exists $\epsilon >0$ such that for every $\delta >0$, $|x-y|<\delta\implies|f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon$.

Which one of the following is true?

$(i)\quad f$ is uniformly continuous.

$(ii)\quad f$ is bounded.

$(iii)\quad f$ is continuous.

$(iv)\quad f$ is constant.

I know definitions of these three.
For some $\epsilon$ there must not exist a $\delta$ satisfying definitions of continuity and uniform continuity.

But how to differentiate between $(iii)$ and $(iv)$?

Can you please explain that?

Comment: Can you produce a discontinuous function satisfying the condition?  Note:  your header refers to "entire" functions, which do not seem relevant here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you choose $y=0$ and you consider another $x$ and  $\delta:= |x|+1$, then

$|f(x)|\leq |f(0)|+\epsilon$ for each $x\in \mathbb{R}$

This means $f$ is bounded.

Moreover an $f$ satisfying your conditions can be

$f(x):= \mathbb{1}_{x=0}$

That is not continuos neither constant.

We consider a bounded function $f$ . Then $f$ satisfying your conditions :

If $|f(x)|\leq M$ for each $x\in\mathbb{R}$ , then we can choose $\epsilon:=2 M$ to get

$|f(x)-f(y)|\leq |f(x)|+|f(y)|\leq M+M=\epsilon$

for each couple $x,y$. So your set is simply the set of bounded functions.

Moreover $f$ could be not measurable. In fact if $S$ is not a measurable set, then

$f:=\mathbb{1}_{S}$

is bounded, and so satisfying your conditions, but it is not a measurable function.

Comment: Follow-up question: whether function $f$ must be measurable?

Comment: @pabodu I answered, good question :)

Comment: @FedericoFallucca In the fifth line what does the $f(x)=1_{x=0}$ means?

Comment: @Tim the function that is $1$ in the point $x=0$ and it is $0$ otherwise